# Trying to make a navigation bar with an Inline UL

Tags: css, uinavigationbar, css-position, html

Basically I am trying to make navigation bar in topNav div which has the website banner set as the background, so I need my nav bar to go on the bottom of the div. I have searched for a way to do this but everything I see says for the containing div have position:relative and the div with the UL position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px;. But what happens is all of my links get piled up. Here is my current Code

CSS

```
.topNav{
    background-image:url(includes/media/banners/hwarang_banner.gif);
    backface-visibility:visible;
    height:135px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
.topNav ul{
    position:relative;
}
.topNav li{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:inline;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="topNav">
<a href="#login" id="login">Login</a>
<span style="color:rgba(238,255,0,1.00); bottom:0; right:0; position:absolute">Alpha Version 0..3</span>
<ul class="topNav">
  <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#calendar"><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#classes"><span>Your Classes</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#event"><span>Event</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#insurance"><span>Insurance</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#purchase"><span>Purchase</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#family"><span>Family</span></a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `margin-top` to set a fixed margin between the navigation bar and the top of the page?

Comment: I probably should have specified more clearly but by piled up I literally mean all of the links are stacked on the z axis if that makes sence given that 2D space doesn't have a z axis.

Comment: Do you have some screen or jsfiddle so I can exactly see what happens?